# Akka Streams: keep the delimiter on framing stage

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I want to split a byte sequence by each line and max line size

```
val f = Source(List(ByteString("a\n")))
  .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 256))
  .runFold(ByteString())(_ ++ _)

Await.result(f, 3.seconds) should be(ByteString("a\n"))
```

The delimiter `\n` will be missing. I want to keep it. Is there a way to do this?

P.S. The issue is described here: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/19664

P.P.S. Just adding `map` section to the flow and farther concatenation of each bytestring with a delimiter is not an option since data is split not just by the delimiter, but also by the `chunkSize` property since it actually comes from the file: `val source = FileIO.fromPath(path, chunkSize = MAX_BYTES)`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you meant by "data is split not just by the delimiter, but also by maximumFrameLength number of bytes", as any frame of size exceeding the specified `maximumFrameLength` will fail the stream.

Comment: Your right. I thought it is being split into pieces without failing the flow. Although, the code here is simplified. The data comes from a file, and it is possible to specify the size of a byte chunk like this:
val source = FileIO.fromPath(path, chunkSize = MAX_BYTES)
So it is being split anyway

Comment: If you're indeed using `Framing.delimiter` followed immediately by a `runFold`, wouldn't `runFold(ByteString())(_ ++ _ ++ ByteString("\n"))` reproduce exactly all the removed `\n` for you?

Comment: No, runFold is just an example. Also, in my case IRL the number of possible rows will be higher than the total number of delimiters, so this kind of concatenation will add extra delimiters that are not acceptable